# How do I find out what's wrong with a uPVC window where the handle turns but it doesn't open?

Tags: windows

How do I find out what's wrong with a uPVC window where the handle turns but it doesn't open?

It seems like one of the hidden latches along the edge isn't undoing because one side of the window moves out a couple of mm when you lean on it but the other side doesn't. It's a horizontal window with the handle at the bottom.

The bottom left moves a bit, the bottom right doesn't:

[image: window]

Is it worth taking the glazing out and / or removing the handle, and how do you do it?

Comment: to remove the handle (get to the screws attaching the handle to the window frame), pop-off the two small circular plastic covers covering the screws (something like a pocket knife blade works well for this). To remove the glazing get something like a thin but sturdy decorators scrapper & work it (very) carefully between the window frame and the window (framing) beads that are holding the glazing in place (is normally easier to pop out one of longer beads first, as it hoffers "greater workability" due to its length).

Comment: got handle off, didn't show me much, just the three hole in the plastic it's attached through. can't get the beading off at all. damn I hate diy

Comment: see if these help: http://youtu.be/l8HfN1C_wIk & http://youtu.be/xQ-_bm3QeeI -- If still no joy, you might be best contacting a window company & go from there...

Comment: the answer was, hire a professional to come and service all the windows and replace all the handles.